# Do bones in Minetown remember if the fountains have slowed to a trickle?

Tags: nethack

If a player dies in Minetown after being warned by the watchmen to stop dipping in fountains or receiving a message that the flow reduced to a trickle, leaving bones, does another player loading the bones get a new warning when dipping/quaffing from that fountain, or is there a chance of the fountain being destroyed with no warning?

Comment: That's just cruel! (+1)

Comment: A good place to ask if you don't get an answer here is rec.games.roguelike.nethack which has the largest nethack community around.

Comment: Or I could just do the source-diving myself; I was feeling lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested this in wizard mode: If you get a warning in one game, die, and encounter the bones in another game, you will not get a warning in the second game. The fountain will just dry up without warning.